# Error in Comprehensions list but correct in for loop

Tags: python, class

I'm trying to create static variables in a class with exec and Comprehensions list:

```
class DictTranslator:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.create_static_variables()

    def get_value(self, key):

        return self.dict_.get(key)
    
    def create_static_variables(self):
        [exec("self." + str(value) + " = " + str(key))   for key, value in self.dict_.items()]
        
    
class AppImportanceTranslator(DictTranslator):


    dict_ = {
        -1: 'Unknown',
        0: 'Gone',
        1: 'Foreground',
        2: 'ForegroundService'
    }
```

but I've this error:
[NameError: name 'self' is not defined](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jKs3.png)

but I can change the code to:

```
class DictTranslator:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.create_static_variables()

    def get_value(self, key):

        return self.dict_.get(key)
    
    def create_static_variables(self):
        for key, value in self.dict_.items():
            exec("self." + str(value) + " = " + str(key))
        
    
class AppImportanceTranslator(DictTranslator):


    dict_ = {
        -1: 'Unknown',
        0: 'Gone',
        1: 'Foreground',
        2: 'ForegroundService'
    }
```

And this code is correct.

Any idea?

My python version is 3.8.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all:

- [**Don't use list comprehensions for side effects**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5753597/is-it-pythonic-to-use-list-comprehensions-for-just-side-effects). You are creating a list object with `None` references, then discarding it again. That's a waste of computer resources.

  Always use a `for` loop if all you needed was a loop.
- You can set attributes on `self` with the [`setattr()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr). `exec()` **should be a last resort**, as it opens you to all sorts of performance and security issues.

You can use:

```
for key, value in self.dict_.items():
    setattr(self, value, str(key))
```

to achieve the same thing.

Alternatively, give your class a [`__getattr__` hook](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) and have it look up attributes lazily:

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    try:
        return str(self.dict_[name])
    except KeyError:
        # raise an AttributeError instead
        raise AttributeError(name) from None
```

The `__getattr__` hook is called for any attribute not explicitly set on your instance.

Now, for what actually goes wrong:

`exec()` can't see `self` because a list comprehension *is a new scope*, as if you ran:

```
def create_static_variables(self):
    def inner_function():
        for key, value in self.dict_.items():
            exec("self." + str(value) + " = " + str(key))
    inner_function()
```

At compile time, Python can see the `self` in `self.dict_.items()` and bind it as a closure (taking it from the local namespace of the `create_static_variables()` call. But `exec()` doesn't run at compile time and so can only see globals or locals.

You could use `exec(..., globals(), {"self": self})` to pass along the `self` binding in a new local namespace, to work around that.